# Method to sum 2 numbers and return the value

Tags: java

So i'm currently trying to finish off my java corse in school but i'm having problem understanding one of the tasks.

The task in question is: Create a method that sums two numbers and returns the sum. The methodhead should look like this; public static double sum(double nr1, double nr2)
and the problem i'm running in to is that i simply do not understand how to solve the task.

The only way of solving this task is with this code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class AddNumbers {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int x, y, z;
        System.out.println("Enter two integers to calculate their sum ");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        x = in.nextInt();
        y = in.nextInt();
        z = x + y;
        System.out.println("Sum of entered integers = "+z);
    }
}
```

But with this solution i'm not solving the task like

Comment: You don't seem to have written a function `public static double sum(double nr1, double nr2)` as explicitly required in the instructions.

Comment: You haven't created the method as wanted in the task. The problem statement practically tells you exactly what you have to do.

Comment: Also note that if the task requires you to use `double` calling `in.nextInt()` is not going to solve the task either. (I'm not sure why "Create a method that sums two _numbers_ ..." results in you writing "Enter two _integers_" - all integers are numbers but not all numbers are integers).

Answer (score -1):

This may help you

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class AddNumbers
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        double x, y, z;
        System.out.println("Enter two numbers to calculate their sum ");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        x = in.nextDouble();
        y = in.nextDouble();
        z = sum(x,y);
        System.out.println("Sum of entered numbers = "+z);
    }
    public static double sum(double nbr1,double nbr2){
        return (nbr1+nbr2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you think just providing some code to someone who didn't even understand the task is going to help in the long run? Better help him understand what's asked of him and let him try a solution himself. You know "give a man a fish and he'll be fed for one day, teach him fishing ..."

Comment: Thanks, just what i needed. As i did not realy understand how to use the method-head!

Thomas, he gave me the information i needed. Now i understand what for look for and i can go understand how i use method heads properly. But yes i get what you mean.

Comment: @patricmatsson "Google Search: How to write function in java", This is what you needed

Comment: thomas i only gave answer of his question.. please read question first and then comment.